# Azure policy not targetting Windows VM's correctly

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I'm in the middle of writing an Azure Policy to check if hybrid use benefits are enabled. Microsoft provides a built-in policy that will target all virtual machines based on image offerings that are available from the Azure platform. However, some VM's in my subscription are based on migrated VM's and therefor have no link to existing image offerings.

I've found a blog post (https://artisticcheese.wordpress.com/2019/07/04/proper-azure-policy-to-verify-azure-hybrid-benefit-enabled/) that explains how to target virtual machines based on configured OS type rather then image offering.

I've started out small and created the following policy setting:

```
"if": {
    "allOf":[
        {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
        },
        {
            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/storageProfile.osDisk.osType",
            "equals": "Windows"                
        }
    ]
},
"then": {
    "effect": "audit"
}
```

These settings however show all my Windows VM's as non-compliant with the following result:

> Reason for non-compliance:
>   Current value ***must not be equal*** to the target value.
>   Field
>   Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/storageProfile.osDisk.osType
>   Path
>   properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType
>   Current value
>   "Windows"
>   Target value
>   "Windows"

Am I interpreting the "equals" operator wrong here? I would have expected this to turn out as compliant for all Windows-based virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mark resources that are not Windows as noncompliant, you have to change your equals to a not equals. So it would be if it does not equal Windows then it should be non-compliant hence audit.